# proxmox Error: Authentication Failed

Tags: debian, proxmox

I did set up Debian with the latest version of proxmox VE. When i create a new Virtual Machine and i try to connect through console i get this error:

```
Error: Authentication Failed
```

After a research on the web i read that it has to do with the difference on time zones, but the wired thing is that it happens on new Virtual Machines that actually boot from the ISO for the install procedure. The ISOs that i have tried till now are Ubuntu 14.04.3 & Debian wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timezone error on the Proxmox host, not in the vm. Try to setup ntp on the Proxmox host.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but same time, timezone, ntp configured. Still not working. Any ideas?